# What is the source for: One shouldn't name a baby using names from before Abraham

Tags: names, abraham, baby-infant

I've heard or I've been taught one shouldn't name a baby (or take a name, in the case of a ger) from names in the Torah before Abraham, namely Adam, Noah etc.

This makes sense to me, as Abraham is the first Yisraelite/Jew; Abraham started the Jewish *berur*/ refinement to repair the mixups and errors of Adam, Noah, the Erev Rav etc.

But looking for a reference I haven't found one handy.

Are there classical sources for not naming from Torah names before Abraham?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6828/759

Answer (score 17):

[Pitchei Teshuva YD 265:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Pithei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.265.6)

> עיין ב[שו"ת תשובה מאהבה ח"א סימן ל"ה](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19543&st=&pgnum=55) שאין להקפיד מלקרות שמות כשמות שהיה קודם אברהם אבינו ע"ה דלא כה[מבי"ט ח"א סי' רע"ו](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1384&pgnum=153) שכתב דאין ראוי לקרוא בשם אדם או נח או שם ועבר דאין להעלות שם אלא מאברהם ואילך ע"ש דאין לחוש לזה שהרי מצינו רבי בנימין בר יפת ועקביא בן מהללאל וראובן קרא לבנו בכורו חנוך וכ"כ ב[ספר ברכי יוסף](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7670&st=&pgnum=117) עיין שם
> Look at responsum [Teshuva MeAhava 1:35](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19543&st=&pgnum=55) that one should not refrain form naming a child from names that were before Abraham our father, servant of God, unlike the [Mabit 1:276](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1384&pgnum=153) who said it is not appropriate to name with the names Adam or Noah or Shem and Eber for one shouldn't use a name except from Abraham and on, see [Teshuva MeAhava] that one shouldn't worry about this for we find [in the Talmud] Rabbi Benjamin ben Japheth and Akavia ben Mehalalel, and Reuben named his oldest son Enoch, and similarly [against the Mabit] is written in [Birkei Yosef (YD 265:6)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7670&st=&pgnum=117), see there [where he cites [Shiyarei Keneset HaGedola (YD Tur 265:8)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14607&st=&pgnum=215) in agreement against the Mabit].

Comment: See also other references by the Chida - *Shem Hagedolim (Ma'areches Gedolim* 1:34), and *Yosef Ometz* (11:3)

Comment: Also nearly all tanaim/amoraim names are not even in the tanah

Comment: @Ezriel that doesn't seem relevant

Comment: @DoubleAA you think it could be considered better "not in the tanah" than "in the tanah but before avraham" ?
I would've make a kal vahomer but maybe not

Comment: I don't see any reason to compare the two

Comment: Is this your translation? If so, yeyasher kochacha, and I recommend making that explicit in the post.

Comment: Very interesting and perhaps indicative of the Mechaber's (non-)stance is it seems the Mabit and Mechaber were contemporaries in Tzfat https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Joseph_di_Trani

Comment: @NissimNanach That's quite a stretch

Comment: @DoubleAA  ברך תהה ננח יחיה שנה ננח פצ'י"ה

Answer (score 0):

For a closer look at the Mabit I:276 in @Double_AA's answer:

I've copied and partially corrected the OCR text from the pdf:

The chakham R' Eliezer Naro (?) raised a difficulty: 
How could Abraham's seed (zera) be such as Avraham's bondsman Eliezer who said, "If the woman doesn't want to follow me.."
The name of "cursed (arur) Canaan" shouldn't be attached to the blessed (barukh).
And we don't call [people] after their names [of the wicked] [Yoma 38b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.38b.6),
but only with your good name,
after the name of Eliezer ben Moshe Rabbeinu a"h.
It also seems to me that as a matter of straight law (shurat ha-din) that we should not lift up [the other] names that are from Abraham and onwards [that is, to only name from Yitz' or Yaak' and later], "because (Abraham specifically) listened to My voice" etc. and from his children none rose to his preeminence.
And an Yisrael should not a priori be named Adam or Noah,
as those who were sworn off from Noah's children are bad blemishes (mumin bishin) as we've taught that Mishnah in Nedarim, even Shem and Ever.
For we don't give a name except from the name of someone who kept (shamar) the entire Torah.  And those who are called Yafet and so forth from those who preceded Abraham are not included in the set of those who toiled in the Torah and bring ''nachat ruach'' to his Creator,
"growing up in a good name and passing away with a good name" etc.

> רעו.
> החכם‬ ה"ר אליעזר נר"ו‬ הקשי׳ ‫לשאול‬ ‫בזרע‬ ‫אברה׳ ‫כאליעז׳
> ‫עבד‬ ‫אברהם‬ ‫שאמר‬ ‫לא‬ ‫תאבה ‫האשה‬ ‫ללכת ‫אחרי‬ ‫ואין‬
> ‫שם‬ ‫ארור‬ ‫כנען‬ ‫נדבק‬ ‫בברוך  ‫ולא ‫מסקי׳ ‫בשמייהו‬ ‫אלא‬ ‫שמך‬ ‫הטוב‬ ‫על‬ ‫שם‬
> ‫אליעזר‬ ‫בן‬ ‫משה‬ ‫רבי׳ ‫ע"ה‬ ‫וכן‬ ‫נ"ל‬ ‫משורת ‫הדין‬ ‫שאין‬ ‫להעלות‬ ‫שם‬ ‫מאברהם‬ ‫ואילך‬
> ‫עקב‬ ‫אשר‬ ‫שמע‬ ‫אברהם‬ ‫בקולי‬ ‫כו׳‬ ‫ולבניו‬ ‫לא‬ ‫קם‬ ‫כמוהו‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫יקר׳ ‫בישראל‬
> ‫לכתחלה‬ ‫שם ‫אדם‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫נח‬ ‫דהנודר‬ ‫מבני‬ ‫נח‬ ‫מומי‬ ‫ביש׳ ‫כמו‬ ‫ששנינו‬ ‫בנדרים‬
> ‫אפי׳‬ ‫שם‬ ‫ועבר‬ ‫דלא‬ ‫מסקי׳‬ ‫שם‬ ‫אלא‬ ‫בשם‬ ‫מי‬ ‫ששמר ‫את ‫התורה‬ ‫כולה‬
> ‫והנקרא‬ ‫בשס‬ ‫יפת‬ ‫וכיוצא‬ ‫בו‬ ‫מאשר‬ ‫קדמו‬ ‫לאברהם‬ ‫אינו‬ ‫בכלל‬ ‫מי‬ ‫שעמלו‬
> ‫בתורה‬ ‫ועושה‬ ‫נחת‬ ‫רוח‬ ‫ליוצרו‬ ‫גדול‬ ‫בש"ט‬ ‫ונפטר‬ ‫בשס‬ ‫טוב‬ ‫וכו׳‬ •‬ ‫

And regarding the difficulty raised by the proof brought by the Rivash z"l for the nusach "and the binding of Yiztchak, to his seed remember, and if you say it's contrary to his reponsum from there, [this is] proof that we ought to say "seed of Yaakob," for [we] don't say those who were sworn off from the seed of Yitzchak are permitted to Esau. Rather, in Abraham specifically it's said to him, of its statement "For in Yizchak will be called to you seed," excluding Yishmael, so [only] in Yitzchak.  But not all of Yitzchak; exclude Esau.  But "in Yitzchak" for it's not written "in Yaakob will be called to you seed" therefore Esau too is called his seed.  Therefore I say my proof is a complete proof, because only this way is it a complete explanation of "will be called to you seed" to exclude Yishmael.  Indeed it's a complete explanation.  "In Yitzchak" [meaning] not all of Yitzchak, to exclude Esau, because otherwise it would have said "Ki Yitzchak yikare lekha zera/ Only Yitzchak is your seed."  But instead it says "Only **in** Yitzchak" which seems a bit similar to "Lekha" – "yikare **le**kha zera/ **to** you will be called seed" so not all of you, namely Esau the wicked.  And since he's not called seed to Abraham, Yitzchak also is not called seed.  And those sworn off from the seed of Yitzchak will be permitted to seed of Esau.
And do not say it's only regarding Abraham that Esau is not called his seed, since he's wicked and is not really his son; but in relation to Yitzchak he's is actual son; even though he's wicked he's called his son.For behold Yishmael who is really son of Abraham is not called his seed due to being unlike him, as it's explained, from the scripture "Yikare lekha zera/ will be called **to** you [i.e. resembling your character] seed" and not Yishmael, and all the more so Esau who did not cherish the seed of Yitzchak even though he was his actual son.  And he's more wicked than Yishmael.  Yishmael did teshuvah, and the fact that it's not taught that those sworn off from the seed of Yitzchak are permitted to Esau, is because there is reason it ought to be necessary to teach that those sworn off from the seed of Abraham are permitted to Yishmael, but after it's been taught [in Mishnah] that those sworn off from the seed of Abraham are permitted to Yishmael and Esau, all the more so those sworn off from the seed of Yitzchak are permitted to Esau, as it says.

> ולענין‬
> ‫מה‬ ‫שהקשית‬ ‫על‬ ‫הראיה‬ ‫שהביא‬ ‫הריב"ש‬ ז"ל‬ ‫על‬ ‫נוסחת ‫ועקדת‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫לזרעו‬
> תזכור‬ ‫ואמרת‬ ‫שהיא‬ ‫נגד‬ ‫תשובתו‬ ‫משם‬ ‫ראיה‬ ‫שצריך‬ ‫לומר‬ זרע ‬‫יעקב‬ ‫דלא‬
> ‫אמ׳ ‫הנודר‬ ‫מזרעו‬ ‫של‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫מותר בעשו‬ ‫אלא‬ ‫באברהם ‫דוקא‬ ‫נאמר‬ ‫לו‬
> ‫ממה‬ ‫שנאמר‬ ‫כי‬ ‫ביצחק‬ ‫יקרא ‫לך‬ זרע‬ ‫להוציא‬ ‫ישמעאל‬ ‫וביצחק‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫כל‬ ‫יצחק‬
> ‫להוציא‬ ‫את ‫עשו‬ אבל ביצחק דלא כתיב ביעבק יקרא לך זרע‬ ע"כ עשו‬
> ‫נמי זרעו ‫נקרא‬ ע"כ ‫ואני‬ ‫אומר‬ ‫דראייתו‬ ‫ראיה‬ ‫גמור׳‬ ‫דכי‬ ‫היכי‬ ‫דהויא‬
> דרשא‬ ‫גמורה‬ ‫יקרא‬ ‫לך‬ ‫זרע‬ ‫להוציא‬ ‫ישמעאל‬ ‫ה"נ‬ ‫הויא‬ ‫דרשא‬ ‫גמור׳‬ ‫ביצחק‬
> ‫ולא‬ ‫כל‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫להוציא‬ ‫עשו‬ ‫מדהוה‬ ‫ליה‬ ‫למכתב‬ ‫כי‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫יקרא‬ ‫לך‬ ‫זרע‬
> ‫וכתב‬ ‫ביצחק‬ ‫דמשמע‬ ‫קצת‬ ‫הדומה‬ ‫לך‬ ‫יקרא‬ ‫לך‬ ‫זרע‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫כולו‬ ‫דהיינו‬ ‫עשו‬
> ‫הרשע‬ ‫וכיון‬ ‫דאינו‬ ‫נקרא‬ ‫זרע‬ ‫לגבי‬ ‫אביהם‬ ‫לגבי‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫נמי‬ ‫אינו‬ ‫נקרא‬
> זרע‬ ‫והנוד׳‬ ‫מזרע‬ ‫של‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫יהיה‬ ‫מותר‬ ‫בזרע‬ ‫עשו‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫תימא‬ ‫דוקא‬ ‫לגבי‬
> ‫אברהם‬ ‫הוא‬ ‫דאינו‬ נקר‫א ‫עשו ‫זרעו‬ ‫כיון‬ ‫שהוא‬ רשע‬ ‫ואינו‬ ‫בנו‬ ‫ממש‬ ‫אבל‬
> ‫לגבי‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫דהויא‬ ‫בנו‬ ‫ממש‬ ‫אע"פ‬ ‫שהוא‬ ‫רשע‬ ‫יקרא‬ ‫בנו‬ ‫דהא‬ ‫ישמעאל‬ ‫דהוא‬
> ‫בנו‬ ‫של‬ ‫אברהם‬ ‫ממש‬ ‫אינו‬ ‫נקרא‬ ‫זרעו‬ ‫על‬ ‫שאינו‬ ‫כיוצא‬ ‫בו‬ ‫כדדרשי׳ ‫מדכתיב‬
> ‫יקרא‬ ‫לך‬ ‫זרע‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫ישמעאל‬ ‫וכ"ש‬ ‫עשו‬ ‫שלא‬ ‫יקר‬ ‫זרעו‬ ‫של‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫אפילו‬
> ‫שהוא‬ ‫בנו‬ ‫ממש‬ ‫והוא‬ רשע‬ ‫יותר‬ ‫מישמעאל‬ ‫וישמעאל‬ ‫עשה‬ תשובה‬ ‫והא‬ ‫דלא‬
> ‫קתני‬ ‫הנודר‬ ‫מזרעו‬ ‫של‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫מותר‬ ‫בעשו משוס‬ ‫דאכתי‬ ‫הוה‬ ‫צריך‬ ‫למתני‬
> ‫הנודר‬ ‫מזרע‬ ‫אברהם‬ ‫מותר‬ ‫בישמעאל‬ ‫אבל‬ ‫בתר‬ ‫דתנא‬ ‫הנודר‬ ‫מזרע‬ ‫אברה׳
> ‫מותר‬ ‫בישמעאל‬ ‫ועשו ‫כ"ש‬ ‫דהנודר‬ ‫מזרע‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫דמותר‬ ‫בעשו‬ ‫כדאמר •

(the remainder is perhaps not as relevant to OP question)..

> ‫ומה‬ ‫שפלפלת‬ ‫לפרש‬ ‫דמדרשא‬ ‫דביצחק‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫כל‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫משמע‬ ‫דעשו‬ ‫נ‬קרא‬
> ‫זרעו‬ ‫של‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫דאי‬ ‫לא‬ ‫קרינא‬ ‫לעשו‬ ‫זרעו‬ ‫של‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫אלא‬ ‫יעקב‬ ‫לבד‬ ‫א"כ‬
> ‫כל‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫יקרא‬ ‫זרע‬ ל‫אברהם ‫ולא‬ ‫מקצתו‬ ‫ע"כ‬ ‫תמהתי‬ ‫על‬ ‫דקות‬ ‫פלפול‬
> ‫זה‬ ‫איך‬ ‫לא‬ ‫דקדקת‬ ‫באופן‬ ‫אחר‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫היה‬ ‫קשה‬ ‫כלל‬ ‫והוא‬ ‫דמדרשא‬ ‫דביצחק‬
> ‫ולא‬ ‫כל‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫משמע‬ ‫דעשו‬ ‫הוא‬ ‫זרע‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫דאם‬ ‫לא‬ ‫היה‬ ‫זרע‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫אלא‬
> ‫יעקב‬ ‫לבד‬ ‫א"כ‬ ‫כל‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫הוא‬ ‫זר‫ע‬ ‫לאברהם‬ ‫אלא‬ ‫שאמר‬ ‫הב"ה‬ ‫לאברהם‬ ‫כי‬
> ‫אע"פ‬ ‫שעשו‬ ‫הוא‬ ‫זרעו‬ ‫ג"כ‬ ‫לא‬ ‫יקרא‬ ‫זרעו‬ ‫אלא‬ ‫ביעקב‬ ‫לבד‬ ‫ודוק׳ ‫לענין‬
> ‫קריאה‬ ‫היא‬ ‫ששלל‬ ‫הכתוב‬ שלא‬ יקרא‬ ‫זרעו‬ ‫לא‬ ‫לענין‬ ‫שאינו‬ ‫זרעו‬ ‫במציאות‬
> ‫ולא‬ ‫יוצא‬ ‫לנו‬ ‫מזה‬ ‫הדין‬ ‫אשר‬ ‫כתבת‬ ‫דהנודר‬ ‫מזרע‬ ‫יצחק‬ אסור‬ ‫בזרע‬ ‫עשו‬
> ‫ויעקב‬ ‫ששניהם‬ ‫נקראו‬ ‫בניו‬ ‫וכן‬ ‫הנודר‬ ‫מזרע‬ ‫בני‬ ‫אברהם‬ ‫אסוד‬ ‫בזרע‬ ‫יצחק‬
> ‫וישמעאל‬ ‫ששניהם‬ ‫נקראו‬ ‫בניו‬ ‫ובנדרים‬ ‫הלך‬ ‫אחר‬ ‫לשון‬ ‫בני‬ ‫אדם‬ ‫דבני‬
> ‫אברהם‬ נקראים‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫וישמעאל‬ בתורה‬ ‫וכן‬ ‫בלשון‬ ‫בני‬ ‫אדם‬ ‫וכן‬ ‫עשו‬ ‫ויעקב‬
> ‫נקראים‬ ‫בני‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫ואינם‬ ‫נקראים‬ ‫זרע‬ ‫אברהם‬ ‫ויצחק‬ ‫שפי׳ ‫כלשון‬ ‫בני‬ ‫אדם‬
> ‫מדרשא‬ ‫דקרא‬ ‫דכתיב‬ ‫כי‬ ‫ביצחק‬ ‫יקרא‬ ‫לך‬ זרע‬ ‫אינו‬ ‫נקרא‬ ‫לך ‫זר‫ע‬ ‫בישמעאל‬
> ‫אלא‬ ‫ביצחק‬ ‫ואפי‬ ‫ביצחק‬ ‫לאכולו‬ ‫אלא‬ ‫מקצתו‬ ‫וכן נרא׳‬ ‫מלשון‬ ‫המשנ׳ ‫ששנינו‬ ‫שם‬
> ‫שאיני‬ ‫נהנה‬ ‫לבני‬ ‫נח‬ ‫מותר‬ ‫בישראל‬ ‫ואסור‬ ‫באומות‬ ‫שאיני‬ ‫נהנה‬ ‫לזרע‬
> ‫אברהם‬ ‫אסור‬ ‫בישראל‬ ‫ומותי‬ ‫באומות‬ ‫העולם‬ ‫פתח‬ ‫בבן‬ ‫וסיים‬ ‫בזרע‬ ‫לומ׳‬
> ‫דדוקא‬ ‫בזרע‬ ‫אברהם‬ ‫הוא‬ ‫דמותר‬ ‫באומות‬ ‫ואפילו‬ ‫בישמעאל‬ ‫ועשו‬ ‫משום‬
> ‫דרש׳ ‫דביצחק‬ ‫לבד‬ ‫יקרא‬ ‫לו‬ ‫זר‫ע‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫כל‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫כדאמ׳ ‫אבל‬ ‫אס‬ ‫אמר‬
> ‫בבני‬ ‫אברהם‬ ‫יהיה‬ ‫אסור‬ ‫בזרע‬ ‫ישמעאל‬ ‫ועשו‬ ‫שנקרא‬ ‫בניו‬ ‫ואפשר‬ ‫שיהיה‬
> ‫אסור‬ ‫ג"כ‬ ‫בזרע‬ ‫בני‬ ‫קטורה‬ ‫ג"כ‬ ‫דכתיב‬ ‫ותלד‬ ‫לו‬ ‫את‬ ‫זמרן‬ ‫ואת‬ ‫יקשן‬ ‫וכו׳‬
> ‫אע״פ‬ ‫שלא‬ נזכר‬ ‫עליהם‬ ‫שס‬ ‫בנים‬ ‫וקרא‬ ‫דלבני‬ ‫הפלגשים‬ ‫אשר‬ ‫לאברהם
> ‫אע"ג ‫דלא‬ ‫מוכח‬ ‫דקאי‬ ‫אשר ‫לאברהם‬ ‫אלבני‬ ‫אלא‬ ‫אפלגשי‬ ‫כיון‬ ‫דכתי׳‬ ‫קודם‬
> ‫ותלד‬ ‫לו‬ ‫קאי‬ ‫נמי‬ ‫אלבני‬ ‫וכן‬ ‫נראה‬ ‫מלשון‬ ‫המשנה‬ ‫שאיני‬ ‫נהנה‬ ‫לזר׳‬ ‫אברה׳‬
> ‫אסור‬ ‫בישראל‬ ‫ומותר‬ ‫באומוח‬ ‫העולם‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫אמר‬ ‫ומותר‬ ‫בישמעאל‬ ‫ועשו‬ ‫אלא‬
> ‫שכלל‬ ‫אותם‬ ‫בכלל‬ ‫שאר‬ ‫האומות‬ ‫והס‬ ‫בני‬ ‫קטורה‬ ‫להשמיענו‬ ‫דוקא‬ ‫כשאמ׳‬
> ‫זרע‬ ‫אברהס‬ ‫היא‬ ‫דמותר‬ ‫אפילו‬ ‫בישמעאל‬ ‫ועשו‬ דאינם‬ ‫נקראים‬ ‫זרעו‬ ‫מדרש׳‬
> ‫דקרא‬ ‫וכ"ש‬ ‫בני‬ ‫קטורה‬ ‫אבל‬ ‫אם‬ ‫אמר‬ ‫שאיני‬ נהנה‬ ‫מבני‬ ‫אברהם‬ ‫יהיה‬
> ‫אסור‬ ‫באומוח‬ ‫שיצאו‬ ‫ממנו‬ ‫אפילו‬ ‫מבני‬ ‫קטורה‬ ‫וא"כ‬ ‫צדק‬ ‫רש"י‬ ‫ז"ל‬ ‫במה‬
> ‫שכתב‬ ‫ולא‬ ‫כל‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫ועשו‬ ‫אינו‬ ‫נקרא‬ ‫זרע‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫וכתבת‬ ‫דלא‬ ‫ידעת‬ ‫מנין‬
> ‫לו‬ ‫והיינו‬ ‫משום ‫דדוקא‬ ‫לענין‬ ‫קריאה‬ ‫הוא‬ ‫דמסיק‬ ‫ליה‬ ‫דמפי׳ ‫ליה קרא
> ילא לענין‬ ‫שאינו‬ ‫זרעו‬ ‫ובניו‬ ‫וכן‬ ‫דייק‬ ‫רש"י‬ ‫ז"ל‬ ‫שכתב‬ ‫אינו‬ ‫נקרא‬ ‫זרע‬
> יצחק ולא כתב אינו זרע יצחק •
> גם מה שהביא ‫הרב יוסף ‫נר"ו‫
> ‫בב"י‬ ‫דברי‬ ‫הרמב"ם‬ ‫ז״ל‬ ‫ופירש‬ ‫דבריו‬ ‫דישמעאל‬ ‫נתמעט‬ ‫מדא׳‬ ‫יצחק‬ ‫ליעקב‬
> ‫ויתן לך‬ את‬ ברכת ‫אברהם ‫נראה ‫שסברתו ‫הוא‬ ‫שמן‬ ‫הכתוב‬ ‫של‬ כי ביצח׳
> יקרא‬ לך זרע נתמעט עשו‬ ‫ומן‬ ‫הכתוב‬ ‫של‬ ‫ויתן‬ ‫לך‬ ‫את ברכת אב‬ הם
> שהיא‬ והיה ברכה אמר ואעשה‬ ‫לגוי‬ ‫גדול‬ ‫וכו׳ נתמעט‬ ‫ישמעאל שברכת
> אברהם‬ ‫שהיתה‬ ‫ראויה‬ גם‬ כן ‫לישמעאל ‫שהיה‬ ‫בנו‬ ‫כמו‬ ‫ליצחק‬ שיתן אותה
> ליעקב‬
> [cont'd, end daf]